# Running command prompt commands on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html, command-prompt

In order to start the server for my project I need to give the command "npm run dev" in the terminal.
I need to give the functionality of starting the server on a button click. Hence, I need to give "npm run dev" command when the user clicks the button. How can I do this? I am writing the code using php.

Comment: Using Ajax or html forms, create a form and then when you get the submitted form. try to run your command with shell_exec of php. Notice this function require some access from your sever side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by doing this:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('npm run dev');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. But,I tried this right now, but the page keeps on loading, with no response. I have also checked the path using dir command, it gives proper output, but when i write npm run dev in the shell_exec, it keeps on loading. Any  reason why this might be happening??

Comment: Have u tried printing errors making error reporting ON?

Comment: Yes yes. I did that and solved the problem! Thanks a lot

Comment: Cheeers :) @PariDeshpande